# javascript typeof / NaN confusion

Tags: javascript, variables, return, nan, typeof

So I'm making a small game using the canvas API and and I'm fairly new to Javascript. But while I was working on making the charecter be able to shoot in a full 360 degrees I came across a error in the code below (this function should return the angle between the mouse position and player position nothing else)

```
calculateAngle : function(x,y){

    var opp = 0; //opposite
    var adj = 0; //adjecent
    var rad = 0; //radian
    var ang = 0; //angle

    //side lengths
    var x1 = gfx.player_center_x //the player x position
    var x2 = mouse_x; //the mouse x position
    var y1 = gfx.player_center_y; //the player y position
    var y2 = mouse_y; //the mouse y position

    //find 2 lengths of the triangle
    opp = (y2 - y1);
    adj = (x2 - x1);

    //find the missing angle between the adjecent and hypotenuse
    rad = Math.atan2(adj, opp);
    ang = rad * 180 / Math.PI;

    //-------------------------//
    console.log(ang); //prints: NaN
    console.log(typeof ang); //prints: number 
    //------------------------//

    return ang;
}
```

When executed its returns NaN but ang is a number!
Why does javascript think the variable ang not a number? Its declared as 0 which typeof returns number, please help!

UPDATE: Careless error made, x1 and y1 ect changed location and I forgot to implement it, thanks for you answers though

Comment: Where do you get `mouse_x` and `mouse_y` from?

Comment: Variables don't have types. `ang` isn't necessarily a Number - it initially stores a Number (`0`)...which `typeof` indicates is a Number. `NaN` means the most recent value (calculation) of `ang` has a result that is determined to not be a number. The calculation determined it's not a number, so it returns `NaN`. Looking at the calculation (`rad * 180 / Math.PI`), I'd assume there's a "problem" with `rad` in order to make that calculation go wrong

Comment: rad is probably NaN already

Comment: It seems to me that it is most likely not rad. You can multiply strings and they will convert to number types. Where I do suspect there is an issue is with x1, x2, y1 or y2. One of those is probably either a string or already NaN since you cannot subtract strings.

Comment: @tomysshadow `rad` **is based off of** `x1`, `x2`, `y1` or `y2`, so that is the problem in the `ang` calculation. You're right though - the problem is probably in an earlier calculation (like for `opp` or `adj`). And you can subtract strings (they are coerced by the operator to complete the operation), as long as they represent numbers.

Answer (score 1):

NaN is a special value. Internally it's a number, but it's a specific value that's given the special meaning of "this value is mathematically undefined". Any operation that results in an undefined number (such as `0/0`) results in NaN, but it's still a number! Just not a defined number.

`Math.atan2` is implemented in such a way that it cannot return `NaN` (because it handles the "edge cases" where `y/x` would be `Infinity` - another "number" that isn't a defined number) so it seems almost certain that your `NaN` is coming from the calculation of `opp` and/or `adj`. You should log these values and see what's up.

Comment: And since opp/adj is coming from x1, x2, y1 and y2, the way the character's and or mouse's position is being calculated is most likely the issue. Perhaps he is trying to get the character's position using CSS, causing the problem. I recommend that the character's position be stored in a variable rather than trying to access the value from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

NaN is a IEEE 754 “Not-a-Number” value. In javascript it belongs to the number type even it is known as NaN(Not a Number). It's a quirks of javascript. Even according to
IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754):
arithmetic formats: sets of binary and decimal floating-point data, which consist of finite numbers (including signed zeros and subnormal numbers), infinities, and special "not a number" values (NaNs).